# Código com Sockets travando no meio

Tags: c, linux, unix

Por conta da matéria de redes da faculdade, ultimamente eu tenho tido experiências para aprender a lidar com sockets em C. Mas hoje, tentando desenvolver um jogo da vela para praticar, passei por um problema um tanto peculiar. Aparentemente, o código que escrevi não possui nenhum erro de sintaxe ou algo do tipo, mas ao tentar rodar após compilar com o GCC (5.4), acontece do programa travar no segundo printf com "Tudo certo!", após a opção "2" ser armazenada e inserida na variável "tipo", bem no else if. Se alguém quiser ou puder, eu me sentiria até agradecido em receber algum feedback sobre o código:

```
    else if(tipo == 2){
    h = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");
    if(h == NULL){
        printf("Impossível localizar o host");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Setup do servidor. Primeiro faz a cópia bit-a-bit do endereço do server para a struct, depois se seta o sin_family na struct e então a porta
    memcpy((char *) &jog1.sin_addr.s_addr, h->h_addr_list, h->h_length);
    jog1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    jog1.sin_port = htons(PORTA);

    jog2.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    jog2.sin_port = (0);
    jog2.sin_family = AF_INET;

    soquete = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(soquete < 0){
        printf("\nOps! Erro ao criar o soquete... Tente novamente\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    binded = bind(soquete, (struct sockaddr *) &jog2, sizeof(jog2));
    if(binded < 0){
        printf("\nErro ao bindar a porta! Tente novamente\n");
        close(soquete);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nTudo certo! Enviando dados ao jogador 1");
    printf("...");
    printf("\nTudo certo! Enviando dados ao jogador 1");
    printf("\nTudo certo! Enviando dados ao jogador 1");
    clilen = sizeof(jog2);
    msg[0] = (char) PRONTO;
    envio = sendto(soquete, msg, sizeof((char) PRONTO) + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &jog1, sizeof(jog1));
    resposta = recvfrom(soquete, msg, MAX_MSG, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &jog1, &clilen);
    if(msg[0] == (char) PRONTO){
        printf("\nJogador 1 conectado com sucesso! %u:%u", ntohl(jog1.sin_addr.s_addr), ntohs(jog1.sin_port));
    }
    else{
        printf("\nErro! Comando inválido recebido!");
        close(soquete);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: O codigo não está completo. Certamente o erro está no tamanho do buffer `msg` passado para `sendto()`. A expressão `sizeof((char) PRONTO) + 1` é bem estranha!

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback! ^-^

Na verdade eu não postei o código completo pois sou novato no fórum, e quando fui fazer a colagem, ficou todo quebrado. Eu tentei tirar o "+ 1" e não funcionou, como também definir previamente um tamanho do buffer do array msg, mas ainda assim, o erro bizarro continua. Apenas retificando, tem uma sequência de 4 printf() nesse código, mas por alguma razão, o programa sempre trava no terceiro.Também um adendo, "PRONTO" é um "sinal" que eu criei num enum (acabei de aprender isso, hehehe) pro cliente ou o servidor enviarem um pro outro quando estiverem prontos.